# How to synchronize DataTables with database

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm creating a small wpf project which involves users registration. In this project I'm using dataAdapter to load data from database to datatables.

```
con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

string query = "select * from Users;";
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
da = new SqlDataAdapter();

da.SelectCommand = cmd;

users = new DataTable();
con.Open();
da.Fill(users);
```

Database have 6 columns Id which is auto increment, username, password, name and two int type columns with default value to Zero. Here is database schema.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [username]   NVARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [password]  NVARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [name]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [attempted] INT           DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [correct]   INT           DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([username] ASC)
);
```

Whenever I insert new user into datatable I only provide username, password and name remaining field should be filled automatically but datatable only save provided fields and remaining are left blank and when I call

```
da.update(users);
```

it update data in database and remaining fields are filled automatically butt datatable still contain those fields as empty columns.

[image: Image without user Id]

But I need user Id to update or delete user. Problem is how can I sync datatable with database for updated fields so I could use them for further operations. Thanks in Advance for your assistance.

**Update:**
Insert query and parameters are given below

```
query = "insert into Users (username, password, name)values(@u, @p, @n)";
SqlCommand insertcmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
insertcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("u", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20, "username"));
insertcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("p", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20, "Password"));
insertcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("n", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "name"));

da.InsertCommand = insertcmd;
```

Comment: Warning - you're storing passwords in plaintext in your database. This is *not* a good practice. Passwords should be one way hashed and salted. It is important to follow good security practices.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But this project is just a home assignment for practice. So no security concerns at the moment.

Comment: Nothing in the question is WPF related. Removed irrelevant tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following parameterized insert query to update Id field in dataTable on the basis of Id generated by database.

```
query = "insert into Users (username, password, name)values(@u, @p, @n); set @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
insertcmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
insertcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("u", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20, "username"));
insertcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("p", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20, "Password"));
insertcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("n", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "name"));

SqlParameter Id = new SqlParameter("Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id");
Id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

insertcmd.Parameters.Add(Id);

da.InsertCommand = insertcmd;
```

Complete explanation given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0(v=vs.110).aspx) with stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

After the insert command do thes to get the ID:

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
int newId = Convert.ToInt32( cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Then add the newId to the right place

This is an example:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Products (ProductName, UnitPrice) VALUES (@ProductName, @Price); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()", conn); 
int newId = Convert.ToInt32( cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to C# I'm using dataAdapter to update database can you explain where I have to place this peace of code to get Id.

Comment: This is an example:      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Products (ProductName, UnitPrice) VALUES (@ProductName, @Price); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()", conn);

Comment: Got it going to try it

Comment: Got new problem I'm not calling SqlCommand separately I'm just calling

    da.update();

Which calls insert SqlCommand and even if I will call it explicitly then how can i decide returned id belongs to which row?

Comment: +1 for giving idea of execution of more than one queries at once in insert command and thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a stored procedure, make sure to declare the id parameter as an output parameter.

```
create procedure dbo.SaveUser
(
    @id int = null out,
   ...
)
as
begin

     --insert goes here

     set @id = scope_identity()
end
```

Comment: I'm new to c# can you explain Stored procedure?

Comment: After doing a lot of brainstorming, somehow I managed to understand stored procedure then change it according to my requirements.